# How to secure my laravel app from Cross-Site Scripting?

Tags: javascript, laravel

I read an article about the Cross-Site Scripting and i wanted to know if my app  is vulnerable to these type of actions.

I have some modules in my app that require long description. So i use summernote editor.In the front in order to display the text correctly i must use {!!  !!}.Is it dangerous to use them in my views to Display Unescaped Data ?

Comment: You can read more on this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/csrf)

Comment: ah yes i already have an idea about that so if i use csrf token as show in the docs which i already did i will avoid these attacks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have some modules in my app that require long description. So i use summernote editor.In the front in order to display the text correctly i must use {!! !!}.Is it dangerous to use them in my views to Display Unescaped Data ?

Yes, it is. Never trust the user. Never rely on client side escaping. You need to escape this on the server side.

I am using [Laravel Purifier](https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier), which you can use to escape all html tags, or you can define, which tags are allowed (e.g. on a textfield something like `<h1>` or `<strong>` should be allowed, but you would need to remove all `<script>` tags.

Laravel includes csrf token management out of the Box, so you are save to cross side attacs.

**EDIT**

As the TE asked in the comments, this is how you use Purifier:

After installation, you can define in the [configuration](https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier#configuration) multiple configurations for the escaping (e.g. if you have different textares, in one you want to allow the `<h1>` and in an other not). In the `HTML.Allowed =>` you write all tags that are allowed to use, in the `CSS.AllowedProperties =>` you set the allowed style changes (e.g. `color`).

To than escape an input, just use `clean($input, 'Configurationname');`, where `Configurationname` is the name of the configuration. The default value is `default`.

Comment: I think this is the best thing that i should do.I just want to know how can i define wich is allowed and which is blocked ?

Comment: Clad I could help! https://youtu.be/_md2zRrPAhA here is a good youtube video I've learned the basics. If you have a question, just ask :)

Answer (score 0):

It's dangerous to display unescaped data in your views, especially one that came from user's input. E.g. a user can save a JS script through that form that would be runned on this page.

In cases when you can't use {{ }} to prevent XSS attacks, you can filter the input data just before storing it to a database. For example with regexp you can remove `<script>` tags or you can validate request input with `not_regex:pattern` first.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use {!! !!} unless you're very sure what you're displaying is entirely safe. Use {{ }} instead. Also make sure you're using laravel's csrf token.